# How to factor a modulus into 2 primes given 2 equations with the factors as the 2 unknowns?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, chinese-remainder-theorem

Given the following

$N = p*q$

and the following 2 equations

$r1 = (a*p + b*q)^x \mod N$

$r2 = (c*p + d*q)^y \mod N$

$r1$, $r2$, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $x$, $y$ and $N$ are all known. The only unknowns here are the 2 factors of $N$, i.e. $p$ & $q$

How do I go about solving these to find $p$ & $q$?

I am sitting on this for the past one day, but have no clue where to start. Does anyone have any hints on how to go about approaching these kinds of problems?

All the numbers involved here are really huge numbers.

**UPDATE:** From the comments, I have reached the next stage. If you do a binomial expansion, all terms except the first & last term involve (pq), so can they can be removed from the equation. So we end up with

$r1 = (a*p)^x + (b*q)^x \mod N$

$r2 = (c*p)^y + (d*q)^y \mod N$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: what do expansions look like ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee - I don't understand - x & y are huge numbers. How would I expand the equations?

Comment: all terms except first and last have  $N$ as a factor

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee - i don't see how (cp+dq) or cp or dq have N as a factor. Can you point me to something I can read to understand this better?

Comment: second termmof expansion is a coefficient times  $(cp)^{y-1}(dq)$   add 1 to the later exponent and subtract from the former to get the next term without coefficient ...

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem  may help

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee - so I can remove all the middle terms because they are a multiple of N. So what remains behind is $(ap)^x + (bq)^x \mod (pq)$ and $(cp)^y + (dq)^y \mod pq$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I have to now convert this into a linear equation in p & q, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: **Steps**:

1) Realize the expansions are congruent to the first and last terms
2) Realize you can mod  $a,c$ by $q$ and $b,d$ by $p$
3) Realize you can mod $x,y$ by $\phi(N)$
4) Realize you can then expand and repeat as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Suppose for the moment that $x=y$. Can you solve for $p^x,q^x$? From here, can you solve for $p,q$?

(2) Now reduce general $x,y$ to the $x=y$ case. Compute $r_1'=r_1^z\bmod N$ and $r_2'=r_2^w\bmod N$. The goal is to have $r_1'=(ap+bq)^{x'}\bmod N$ and $r_2'=(cp+dq)^{x'}\bmod N$, for some positive integer $x'$. What $z,w$ will accomplish this? Now apply the algorithm from (1) to $r_1',r_2'$ using $x'$.